# Jmeter API Time consumption calculation

Tags: jmeter

In a thread i am passing 5 sample is there any way to get the total response time of starting and ending sample. Need to calculate the time from starting api time as start time and ending time of last response among the 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the requests under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), it calculates cumulative time for all its children execution.

[image]

More information: [What is JMeter’s Transaction Controller?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller)